# N-Channel MOSFET Drain-Source voltage

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics

Right now I'm using an N-Channel MOSFET. I am inputting a 2V pk-pk square wave into the gate, the drain is connected to a bare wire (that is connected to nothing) and the source is connected to ground. For some reason there's a voltage reading in the drain of my MOSFET. Is this normal?

Comment: What device and how are you doing the measurement?

Comment: Whenever you connect a high impedance voltmeter/oscilloscope etc. to anything you will have some "voltage reading". Especially if there is a signal nearby.

Comment: I was using an oscilloscope to do the measurements. Sorry first time with MOSFETs, so I only know how they work based on what I learned from Youtube

Comment: A graph of the measured signal would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you see just the "edges" (positive/negative peaks at the times when there are rising/falling edges at the input signal) it can be explained by the capacitance between gate and drain.

Comment: How does the capacitance create these sharp edges? What should I be googling to learn more about this phenomenon?

Comment: @Kurst: The capacitance doesn't create the sharp edges; they are there already in your square wave signal at the gate. DC can not pass a capacitor; quick voltage changes can. You should learn how a capacitor works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a capacitance between gate and drain. So some signal may get to drain.

**UPDATE:**

When you leave drain floating, then that circuit behaves "almost" like this:
[image]
It is very simplified, but I think it is OK for explanation.

I wired it on breadboard, and this is the response:
[image]
yellow = input signal (1MHz square, 5Vpp)

blue = output signal (on floating drain)

So, yes, it is normal, that signal gets from gate to floating drain.

Comment: Please explain how this will happen and provide a diagram, one line answers are low quality.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer